# Angular track by object.id

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have following JSON data received form REST api.

```
 [
  {
    "names": {
      "en": "test123"
    },
    "children": [],
    "id": "68d87e8c-42f5-4f11-b25a-b30624246c3b",
    "version": 1,
    "code": "0",
    "order": 0,
    "country": "HR",
    "name": "test123",
    "parent": null,
    "selected": false,
    "hasQuestions": false,
    "level": 1,
    "state": "original",
    "hasChildChapters": false
  },
  {
    "names": {
      "en": "test456"
    },
    "children": [],
    "id": "d175e6d1-874e-4909-afb2-790c0a940c3f",
    "version": 1,
    "code": "0",
    "order": 0,
    "country": "HR",
    "name": "test456",
    "parent": null,
    "selected": false,
    "hasQuestions": false,
    "level": 1,
    "state": "original",
    "hasChildChapters": false
  }
]
```

I'm trying to display it using  directive ng-repeat. Using track by object.id. 
It is used like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="chapter in chapters | filter: search track by chapter.id">
```

But the problem is that the ngRepeat:Dupes error still appear. I have checked the data contained in JSON, but there is no duplicite id in it. Do you know why the ngRepeat:Dupes error persists?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data given, no duplicate error is thrown, below is jsfiddle.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="chapter in chapters | filter: search track by chapter.id">{{chapter.id}}</div>
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.chapters = [{
        "names": {
            "en": "test123"
        },
            "children": [],
            "id": "68d87e8c-42f5-4f11-b25a-b30624246c3b",
            "version": 1,
            "code": "0",
            "order": 0,
            "country": "HR",
            "name": "test123",
            "parent": null,
            "selected": false,
            "hasQuestions": false,
            "level": 1,
            "state": "original",
            "hasChildChapters": false
    }, {
        "names": {
            "en": "test456"
        },
            "children": [],
            "id": "d175e6d1-874e-4909-afb2-790c0a940c3f",
            "version": 1,
            "code": "0",
            "order": 0,
            "country": "HR",
            "name": "test456",
            "parent": null,
            "selected": false,
            "hasQuestions": false,
            "level": 1,
            "state": "original",
            "hasChildChapters": false
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75sdsuz2/2/

Comment: Thanks, a tried it many times and I have following data. The first data with 99 items is [link](http://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/784e6b) and it is displayed with no problem.

Comment: Thanks, a tried it many times and I have following data. The first data (lets say data A)with 99 items is [link](http://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/784e6b) and it is displayed with no problem.  Then I have the second data(lets say data B)  [link](http://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/77faeb) which have only 10 items. Using angular I have prepared a switch button between the data A and B. But after I switch from data A to data B the problem with duplicities appears. I manually  checked the duplicity of id, but there is no duplicite Id. I'm totally confused why the error raises.

Comment: @tsos updated the fiddle with your given data and using interval with the switching between the two values for every second and it is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/75sdsuz2/6/

Comment: @tsos update fiddle with the switching the value on clicking the button http://jsfiddle.net/75sdsuz2/7/